# How can I get a document snapshot of firebase collection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to let user search hashtags from firebase collection. but im a bit struggling with that
Heres how im trying to get snapshot of document

```
class Videos {
  final String categorie;
  final String commentcount;
  final String hashtag1;
  final String hashtag2;
  final String hashtag3;
  final String likes;
  final String previewimage;
   final String profilepic;
  final String sharecount;
  final String uid;
  final String username;
  final String videourl;

  Videos({this.commentcount, this.hashtag1, this.hashtag2, this.hashtag3, this.likes, this.previewimage, this.profilepic, this.sharecount, this.uid, this.videourl, this.categorie, this.username});
}
```

```
var  videoscollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos');

  Videos videosfromsnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return Videos(
      categorie:snapshot.data()['categorie'],
      commentcount:snapshot.data()['commentcount'],
         hashtag1:snapshot.data()['hashtag1'],
  hashtag2:snapshot.data()['hashtag2'],
   hashtag3:snapshot.data()['hashtag3'],
   likes:snapshot.data()['likes'],
      previewimage:snapshot.data()['previewimage'],
      profilepic:snapshot.data()['profilepic'],
       sharecount:snapshot.data()['sharecount'],
          uid:snapshot.data()['uid'],
      username:snapshot.data()['username'],
   videourl:snapshot.data()['videourl'],

    );
  }

 Stream<Videos> get  provideDocumentFieldStream {

    return videoscollection.doc().snapshots().map(videosfromsnapshot);
       
}
```

And then im trying to use it here

```
 searchResults() {
    var showResults = [];
    if (widget.searchinginput.text != "") {
      for (var tripsnapshot in _allResults) {
        var title = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .hashtag1
            .toLowerCase();
        print(title);
        var title2 = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .hashtag3
            .toLowerCase();
        print(title);
        var title3 = DatbaseService.instance
            .videosfromsnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .hashtag2
            .toLowerCase();
        print(title);
        if (title.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase()) ||
            title2.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase()) ||
            title3.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase())) {
          setState(() {
            nosuerfound = true;
          });
          showResults.add(tripsnapshot);
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        nosuerfound = true;
      });
      showResults = List.from(_allResults);
    }
    setState(() {
      _resultsList = showResults;
    });
  }

  getusers() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('videos').get();

    setState(() {
      _allResults = qn.docs;
    });
    searchResults();
    return "Complete";
  }
```

So what im trying is user searching hashtags and every video have 3 hashtags and when user typed one hashtags I wanna displaying the the 3 hashtags of the video but its not working I think there should be something wrong with the document snapshot .
heres my firebase

[image]

Here is where it throws

```
class Openmyprofil extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController searchinginput;

  const Openmyprofil({Key key, this.searchinginput}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OpenmyprofilState createState() => _OpenmyprofilState();
}

class _OpenmyprofilState extends State<Openmyprofil> {
  List _allResults = [];
  List _resultsList = [];

  Future resultsLoaded;
  bool nosuerfound = false;
  var titles;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.searchinginput.addListener(_onsearchChanged);
     widget.searchinginput.text;
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    resultsLoaded = getusers();
  }

  _onsearchChanged() {
   
    setState(() {
      nosuerfound = false;
    });
    searchResults();
  }

  

  searchResults() {
    var showResults = [];
    if (widget.searchinginput.text != "") {
      for (var tripsnapshot in _allResults) {
        titles = tripsnapshot;
        var title = DatbaseService.instance
            .userDataFromSnapshot(tripsnapshot)
            .username
            .toLowerCase();
        if (title.contains(widget.searchinginput.text.toLowerCase())) {
          setState(() {
            nosuerfound = true;
          });
          showResults.add(tripsnapshot);
          print(tripsnapshot);
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        nosuerfound = true;
      });
      showResults = List.from(_allResults);
    }
    setState(() {
      _resultsList = showResults;
    });
  }

  getusers() async {
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('meinprofilsettings').get();
    setState(() {
      _allResults = qn.docs;
    });
    searchResults();
    return "Complete";
  }
```

Comment: what happens when you run this code?

Comment: it says int is not a subtype of string and it dont works . When i typed in a letter its says no hashtags found thats the default text that i show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, first thing to do is change this:

```
commentcount:snapshot.data()['commentcount'],
```

To this:

```
commentcount:snapshot.data()['commentcount'].toString(),
```

This is causing your error `int is not a subtype of string`, because comment count in firebase, is an `int` based on the picture you posted. Eliminate this error, then we proceed further, it might even solve your problem if everything else is figured out correctly.

Do the same thing for `shareCount`

```
sharecount:snapshot.data()['sharecount'].toString()
```

Comment: It says now type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: First error gone. This new error is being caused because `likes` in firebase is a list. Change it to `likes:snapshot.data()['likes'].length.toString()`. Do the same thing for shares as you did for comment count, I updated my answer.

Comment: Now it says setState() called after dispose(): _OpenmyprofilState#36da9(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)

Comment: This error is for a different post, but before your setStates, use this line: `if(!mounted) return;`
Please consider marking this as an answer if it helped you debug your code, and also consider reading further about debugging. The errors tell you exactly what you need to do and where to look, we just went through 3 bugs